# Need help with calling an API using an Arduino system

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, c++

As stated in the title, I need help with calling an API. I'm trying to integrate make a call using the Verkada API but it seems to be using a cURL library that I'm not entirely certain I can get to work with my Arduino Mega2560 and an ethernet shield. The API documentation gives this C/C++ code shown below but with no guidance on how to use it

```
CURL *hnd = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.verkada.com/cameras/v1/alerts?org_id=ORGANIZATION_ID&include_image_url=false&page_size=100");

struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "accept: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "x-api-key: API_KEY");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
```

This code and the documentation can be found here: https://apidocs.verkada.com/reference/getnotificationsviewv1

If there's any more necessary information I haven't I'm happy to look more and provide it. If I need to be taking a different approach I would also really appreciate some advice on that.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you can use the ArduinoHttpClient library

Comment: I've been looking at the HTTPClient Library. Is there a  good way to think about translating the above code in a way that would work how it expects it to work? Verkada expects an organization ID and API Key and I don't know if that translates direct into the functions included in the library or works like a standard authorization

Comment: use a web browser, such as Chrome to retrieve the data ... use the development tools in Chrome to see what data is passed back and forth between the browser and the server ... your question is not related to Arduino

Comment: Do you know whether this API can be accessed through unencrypted HTTP? @Juraj: Seems to me that the HTTPClient library does not support HTTPS.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, you are right. then it is not possible with Ethernet shield on Mega. OP has to change to a 32-bit board with SSLClient library with Ethernet library. or instead of Ethernet shield use a WiFi shield or module which provides SSL (WiFi101, esp8266).